# Why doesn't the Rational Root Theorem work on $x^3-6x^2+4x-5=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, cubics

I tried using the Rational Root Theorem on $x^3-6x^2+4x-5=0$. However, I could not find a rational root of the cubic. When I plugged the cubic into Wolfram Alpha, it yielded a very messy real solution:

[image]

> How do you tell whether the RRT doesn't work on a particular cubic of the form $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$? How do you tell whether $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ doesn't have any rational roots?

Comment: The rational root theorem always works, hence the name *theorem*.

Comment: It always works - the root you give is not rational!

Comment: Possibly there is a typo: if the constant term is $5$ vs. $-5$ then it has root $\,x=5,\,$ which is easily found by the Rational Root Test, since it implies that the only possible rational roots are $\,\pm1,\pm 5.\ \ $

Comment: See [cubic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Answer (score 7):

When you apply the rational root theorem, you find *all* the rational roots, if there are any.  If the theorem finds no roots, the polynomial has no rational roots.  (For a cubic, we would observe that the polynomial is irreducible over the rationals.  This is because a factorization of the cubic is either the product of a linear factor and a quadratic factor or it is the product of three linear factors.  Since in either case there is a linear factor, there would be a root in the rationals.  With no rational root, we're done.)

Determining whether a polynomial has rational roots is done by means of the rational root test.  There is no prior test one uses to determine whether to use the rational roots test; one starts with the test to find and remove all the "easy" factors.  (One should also use the polynomial GCD and the derivative to remove repeated roots, but that's outside the scope of your question.)  Only after all the easy roots are removed (or not found) do you move on to hard tools like the cubic formula.

For more discussion, see [casus irreducibilis in the English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis).

Comment: It is not true that no rational roots implies irreducible over $\,\Bbb Q,\,$ e.g. $\,(x^2+1)^2\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque:  Claim is true for cubics, the poster's question domain.  Answer updated with this caveat.

Comment: Glad to see the qualification added. Many students mistakenly believe the unqualified statement to be true. It would be even  clearer to write "this implies" vs. "we would say", since the latter sounds like a definition, exactly the misconception we want to avoid.

Comment: @BillDubuque:  Yes, this is true.  I've been reading (elementary) Galois theory recently and the possible factorings of the cubic is perhaps too clear to me presently.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

The rational roots theorem yields potential *rational* roots.  It says nothing about roots that are not rational.  :)

To detect how many **real** roots there will be, take a look at the [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant).  If $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are roots of the polynomial, then:

$$\Delta = (a_1-a_2)^2(a_1-a_3)^2(a_2-a_3)^2 = b^2c^2-4ac^3-4b^3d-27a^2d^2+18abcd$$

Yuck!  Note that $\Delta \geq 0 \iff$ there are $3$ real roots (counting multiplicity).  Otherwise, there will be one real and two complex roots.

Actually *finding* these roots requires the God-awful cubic formula or certain numerical approximations, such as [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), if you're fine with error.

Comment: If you think the formula for the cubic is awful, check out the quartic....

Comment: Oh God no.  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Quartic_Formula.svg

Answer (score 1):

After some extensive testing of my own on another polynomial that had zeros but could not be determined by the rational roots test I came to the following conclusion:

It appears, that the RRT will only give you $\mathit rational$ numbers as answers. Meaning, a polynomial might very well have zeros but the RRT will not give you any results. That is because said zeros are real numbers which cannot be represented by rational numbers. $(x\in\Bbb R, x \notin\Bbb Q)$

For OP's polynomial $x^3-6x^2+4x-5=0$, doing the RRT quickly leads one to believe that there are no zeros for it ;(it is left to the reader to confirm this as an exercise). It does however have one. Using an online zeros calculator one finds that the zero in question is $x=5.43316142415711$. This number is real (as in $\Bbb R$) and cannot be represented by a fraction.

In conclusion: The RRT will only give you results that are part of $\Bbb R$. There may however be polynomials that do very well possess zeros but those may not be part of $\Bbb R$. I hope this answers the question in the title.